Failed building wheel for pillow-heif with error Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier
While trying to install Wagtail on MacOS Monterey with pip the build fails with many errors like these:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:134:25: error: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Werror,-Wnullability-completeness]
      double   atof(const char *);
                               ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:134:25: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
      double   atof(const char *);
                               ^
                                _Nullable
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:134:25: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
      double   atof(const char *);
                               ^
                                _Nonnull

The final error is:
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow-heif
Failed to build pillow-heif
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pillow-heif)

I looked at similar questions but the answers did not seem to apply to installations with pip.
Is there a workaround for this? Can I install Wagtail without pillow? Thank you for any suggestions.

"Can I install Wagtail without pillow?" Nope, these are required dependencies: Pillow and Willow+heif.

What is your Python/Django version?

My Python version is 3.11.9. Following the Wagtail install instructions, I am installing in a virtual environment and have not installed Django yet.
